# Using image tag to pass a function with 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This piece of code should change the text in a paragraph when the image is clicked. However, the onclick function does not work and the text remains the same. Please see the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<main class="tvfull">
    <p id="text"> myname </p>

    <section class="tv">
        <img class="tv" src="img/television.png">
    </section>
</main>

<main class="remote">
 
    <section class="remote">
        <img class="remote" src="img/remote_base.png">
    </section>

    <section class="buttons">
            <img  src="img/button_me.png" onclick="change()" id="me">
            
    </section>
</main>


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// check if page is fully loaded
window.onload = function() {

}
function change(){
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "You clicked the button";
}
```

Comment: The provided code snippet works as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<main class="tvfull">
    <p id="text"> to be changed </p>

</main>

<section class="buttons">
            <img id="me" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3804997/pexels-photo-3804997.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" onclick="change()">
    </section>
    
<script>
  function change() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "text changed!"
  }  
</script>
```

Can you share the full source code? I tried it and it worked fine.
Did you wrap your JavaScript function in a script tag?

Comment: Is the script.js in the header the file that contains the change function? If yes, you should move the script tag down right before the end of the body tag. Also, you didn't include your change function into the window.onload function.

Comment: Thanks! it works now! Is it good practice to include the script tag at the end? If so, why?

Comment: Nice to hear! Yes, it is. If you include the script in the head and reference any html elements they can't be reached since they are not rendered yet. If you include your script tag after all your elements you ensure that JavaScript knows about these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a div outside the image and move the onclick on it like so:

```
<section class="buttons">
            <div onclick="change()"><img id="me" src="img/button_me.png"></div>
</section>
```

however it should work fine on img too

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.

It might be worth thinking about changing how you are triggering the event, inline `onclick` events can be hard to track. You could use `jquery` to add a `click` event to the image tag by using the reference `$("img#me")` (this finds all `img` tags with an id `me`, bearing in mind ids should be unique so you could just use `$("#me")`).

You can also select the paragraph to change in the same way, using the selector `$("#text")` and then the function `.text()` to change the text within it or `.html()` if you require that funcitonality.

I've also used a link to a placeholder image for the purposes of the answer.

---

```js
// Attach click event to 'img' tag with id 'me'
$("img#me").click(function() {

  // Change text
  $("#text").text("You clicked the button");
  // Or you can use the following if you need to add HTML:
  //$("#text").html("You clicked the button");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="tvfull">
  <p id="text"> to be changed</p>
</main>

<section class="buttons">
  <img id="me" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</section>
```